# Releasing of the associative arrays

Tags: javascript

How to rightly release the associative arrays from memory? Or memory will be released automatically and manually release isn't necessary?

Comment: Javascript is garbage collected and (in modern browsers that aren't bugged) the memory management should work the same as anything that isn't C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is garbage-collected, so you technically don't need to worry about releasing anything.

Comment: I read that IE has some problems with automatic releasing memory

Comment: @Nawa: Ancient versions of IE did have significant issues, but for most people this is not relevant today. If you were one of the people for which it is still relevant, you would already know.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1:2};
delete a;
```

However, this will remove the reference. If there are other variable pointing to this object, object will not be released. Once you have no references left, JS will automatically garbase collect.

Comment: That won't work... you cannot delete variables declared with `var`. For more information, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: I forgot that point. I was trying to illustrate delete and used var by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the answer